# Posting a JSON to a Spring Controller

Tags: java, json, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I'm learning to pass a JSON object through ajax to a Spring Controller.

Found an article, that seems to explain how its done: http://hmkcode.com/spring-mvc-json-json-to-java/

From that point i added a @RequestMapping to the Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get-user-list", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String testPost(@RequestBody ResourceNumberJson resourceNumberDtoJson) {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> I AM CALLED");
        return "111";
    }
```

Then i'm forming my ajax post:

```
var json = {
    "login" : "login",
    "resource_number" : "111",
    "identifier" : "1111",
    "registrator_number" : "11111111111111"
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "/get-user-list",
    dataType : "text",
    data : JSON.stringify(json),
    contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    mimeType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data) { 
            alert(data.id + " " + data.name);
        },
    error:function(data,status,er) { 
            alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
    }

});
```

which is runned from "get-user-list" page.

When i'm trying to run this, i recieve a HTTP 415 error. Spring 4, Jackson 2.4

Cant understand what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTTP 415** means, that the media type is not supported.

Try changing your @RequestMapping annotation to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get-user-list", 
                method = RequestMethod.POST, 
                consumes="application/json")
```

You should also consider testing your REST-service with a client like RESTClient, Postman or even cURL to make sure it is working correctly before you start implementing the jQuery client.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll definitely look up on the RESTClient. Think i found my problem - i misslooked the slash before the url(i think).

Comment: Ok, but this is hardly the cause for HTTP/415.

Comment: The URL came out to be "root/get-user-list" instead of "root/users.../get-user-list". I guess i ren into some other's controller policy.