# Spring mvc server. Trying to post json into controller (The server refused this request )

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have following  json request on view side

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
  sendAjax();
});

function sendAjax() {

$.ajax({
    url: "/shop/main/order/model",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: " { \"totalPrice\": 10, \"custumerName\":\"vasiya\", \"ItemsList\": [ { \"id\": 1,\"name\":\"qqq\",  \"price\": 10, \"count\": 2 } ] }",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    mimeType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.totalPrice + " " + data.custumerName);
    },
    error:function(data,status,er) {
        alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
    }
});
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

`controller` looks like this

```
   @Controller
@RequestMapping("/order")
public class OrderController {

     @RequestMapping(value="/model", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public @ResponseBody  OrderModel post(@RequestBody final  OrderModel model) {
            System.out.println(model.getItemsList());
            System.out.println(model.getTotalPrice());

            return model;
        }


    }
}
```

**OrderModel.java**

```
public class OrderModel implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String custumerName;
    int totalPrice;
    Items[] itemsList;

    public void setTotalPrice(int totalPrice) {
        this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
    }

    public void setItemsList(Items[] itemsList) {
        this.itemsList = itemsList;
    }

    public int getTotalPrice() {

        return totalPrice;
    }

    public Items[] getItemsList() {
        return itemsList;
    }

    public void setCustumerName(String custumerName) {
        this.custumerName = custumerName;
    }

    public String getCustumerName() {

        return custumerName;
    }

    public OrderModel(String custumerName, int totalPrice, Items[] itemsList) {
        this.custumerName = custumerName;

        this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
        this.itemsList = itemsList;
    }
}
```

**Items.java** is a simple POJO class which is designed for mapping  hibernate entities and contains String and long types fields only.

So when I'm trying to access `index.html` it doesn't send back any respone. In   browser's console   i'm getting the   follow:

**POST http://localhost:8080/shop/main/order/model 415 ()**

> HTTP Status 415 -
>
> type Status report
>
> message
>
> description: The server refused this request because the request entity
>   is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the
>   requested method.

Comment: at a first glance, I find a little strange those \" in the request body. try this `data: { totalPrice: 10, custumerName:'vasiya', ItemsList: [ {id: 1,name:'qqq',  price: 10, count: 2 } ] },`

Comment: nope, problem remains

Comment: let me point you [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36084619/740480). Maybe it's the missing `consumes="application/json"` in the`@RequestMapping`

Comment: Yes, I have already noticed that, but it still doesn't work

Comment: I tried to imitate the same request via postman and got the same error, so it seems like it is the server side problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 Things I figured out from your code.
1. You need a messageConverter in your application.

To add message converter you need to add these 2 dependencies in your pom. Check the correct version which is applicable for you.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

2. Add below bean in your dispature-servlet.xml or whatever mvc configuration file you are using.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

After this you will not going to get 415 as your application will find correct message converter.

3. Your OrderModel entity is missing default constructor which will error out once you will do above 2 steps. so add a default constructor.

   ```
   public OrderModel() {    }
   ```

Comment: You goddamn right! Thank a lot.But it works fine without additional bean definition. Is it really  necessary? I had already jackson-mapper-asl in pom, but no jackson-databind, and default constructor.-It seems  like those two  was the main problem.

Comment: Can you send me your dispatcher-servlet.xml? As I tried without message converter and was getting 415. So I added it.

Comment: I think I was missing <mvc:annotation-driven /> in my context configuration file. After adding it. we don't need to define that message converter bean.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending **ItemsList** but in your class it is **itemsList**.

Comment: oh thanks what an embarrassing mistake, but it's still the same result